# Video embed on timeline with custom open graph object

Tags: facebook, object, video, action, facebook-opengraph

So the story is this, I added a custom object to my app called Music Video and an action called Watch. I have all the needed meta tags in my pages to show the flash video, the linter reads them perfectly, it says that the type of share for my object is Video also.

If I post it using the like social plugin the flash video shows just fine but with my custom Watch action just shows the thumbnail and no play button, no nothing.

Do you know any example of apps using the new open graph api to embed video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook currently does not embed Flash video alongside stories generated from the build-in Watch action or on custom actions. Facebook will however embed the video if the URL is organically shared (copy and pasted into the Composer in Facebook) or liked via the Like button.

For now, this means a click on the watch news feed or ticker story will drive the user to your site, where you can authenticate them, play the video, and publish another watch action on their behalf.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Will this change in the future so a video can be embedded in the same way as the like action does today?

Comment: We are experiencing a similar issue, has there been any progress or decision making on whether or not this will be supported in the future? There is a desire to have embedded video along with our custom action/objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when the changes took effect, but you can check it right [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/#video):